# How to build dropdown list with database?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have try to build dropdown list that  bind with database. I found out some errors that i dont really found. Please help, here below is my codes.

```
 strSQL = "SELECT distinct table1.DeptName FROM Table1 " & _
                        "FULL JOIN Table2 on table1.DeptName = Table2.deptname" & _
                        "FULL JOIN Table3 on Table1.deptname = table3.DeptName " & _
                        "Where table1.deptname is not null order by table1.deptname "
            Common.OpenConn()
            Common.execReader(strSQL, params, dt, Common.txn)

            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                DropDownListDept.DataSource = dt
                DropDownListDept.DataTextField = "DeptName"
                DropDownListDept.DataValueField = "DeptName"
                DropDownListDept.DataBind()
                DropDownListDept.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select Department Name", "0"))
            End If
```

error found

> Invalid column name 'DeptNameFULL'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in your sql statement...  The database is looking for a field called "DeptNameFULL" and of course there isn't.

```
strSQL = "SELECT distinct table1.DeptName FROM Table1 " & _
                    "FULL JOIN Table2 on table1.DeptName = Table2.deptname" & _
                    "FULL JOIN Table3 on Table1.deptname = table3.DeptName " & _
                    "Where table1.deptname is not null order by table1.deptname "
```

On the second line - you need a space after "Table2.deptname" - so it should be `Table2.deptname "`  instead.